# How to solve the problem on income and expenditure?

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

Question :

"The annual earning of Mr. Sikkawala is Rs.$4$ lakhs per annum for the first year of his job and his expenditure was $50$%. Later on for the next $3$ years his average income increases by Rs $40000$ per annum and the saving was $40$%, $30$%, $20$%$ of the income. What is the percentage of his total savings over the total expenditure if there is no any interest is applied on the savings for these four years."

Doubt:

I want to have a paradigm thought process behind the problem. Some assistance about the same will be most welcome.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what "lakhs" means. Does going from Rs.4 lakhs a year to Rs 40000 mean that he has had a 1000000% increase in his salary?

Comment: 1 lakh is 100000.

Comment: There is a "paradigm" for solving so-called word problems.  You should have identified the unknown that the problem asks you to find and chosen a variable to designate this unknown so that mathematical expressions can be used.  Sometimes a problem is so simple that the "algebra" is unnecessary (and you proceed directly to the underlying arithmetic), but since you are here to ask for help, that is presumably not your situation.  You give the impression that you did not digest the problem statement before posting, so I'm voting to close.  Please edit to include context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what "paradigm" you are after, but the information given can be summarized in a table:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\text{Year}&\text{Income}&\text{% Savings}&\text{% Expenditures}\\\hline
1&400000&50\%&50\%\\
2&440000&40\%&60\%\\
3&480000&30\%&70\%\\
4&520000&20\%&80\%\end{array}$$

From this you can calculate the actual amount of money saved each year, and spent each year. Sum those up to get total savings and the total expenditures.

I am not entirely sure how to interpret the phrase "percentage of this total savings over the total expenditure". It sounds like they want you to divide the savings by the expenditures and convert that ratio to a percentage. But that is a rather odd and somewhat meaningless value to calculate, so maybe I am misinterpreting the instruction.